# Make an organisation Chart on Latex

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-styles, forest, charts

I am looking to make an organisation chart on latex for a group project. I have never done this before, and I saw that I can use the Forest package or using tikz.

My coworker, made the chart using word, so I want to keep the skeleton, but maybe make it look a bit fancier. 
Does anyone have good knowledge on this? I want to be able to insert the pictures in each box individually (load them).

Thanks

[image]
Edit: Ok I have done a bit of work on that, that is my code

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\newcommand\whitecell[1]{\cellcolor{white}{#1}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[halign= flush center, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large, title={Lecteur DVD LG=Model GSA-H10N}, width=\linewidth/2]
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture1.jpg}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\tcbset{on line,before upper=\strut,width=10cm}

\vspace{10px} %%%%%%%%% Adding space %%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
\tcbox[tcbox width=auto]{PHASES DE DEMONTAGE}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\tcbox[tcbox width=auto limited]{ATTACHEMENTS}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}[1]{fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large, sidebyside, lefthand width=6.5cm,
  enhanced,
  title=#1,
  overlay unbroken and first ={
    \node[anchor=north east,rounded corners,draw=black!80,fill=gray!30,line width=0.5mm,text width=2.5em,align=center,minimum height=4ex] at ([xshift=-\marginparsep]frame.north west) {\thetcbcounter};
  }
}

\vspace{10px}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 1
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
\begin{mybox}{Démontage du boitier}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture2.JPG}% 
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture3.jpg}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 4 min.\\ 30 sec.
\end{mybox}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4.5cm,
halign=center,valign=center,
square]
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{Picture4.JPG}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 2
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
\begin{mybox}{Démontage de la carte mère}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture2.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture5.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 1 min.\\ 25 sec.
\end{mybox}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4.5cm,
halign=center,valign=center,
square]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 3
\begin{mybox}{Démontage du moteur d'ouverture du lecteur}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture6.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture7.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 45 sec.
\end{mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 4
\begin{mybox}{Démontage de la tête de lecture}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture8.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture9.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 1 min.
\end{mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large, title={Première étape de démontage}, width=15cm, halign title=flush center]
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{Picture10.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps total:} 7 min. 30 sec.\\\\
\underline{Eléments démontés:}\\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Boitier aluminium
  \item Carte mère
  \item Support CD plastique
  \item Moteur d'ouverture du lecteur
  \item Tête de lecture
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 5
\begin{mybox}{Démontage de la partie métallique}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture8.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture9.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 30 sec.
\end{mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 6
\begin{mybox}{Démontage de }
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture8.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture9.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 1 min.
\end{mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phase 7
\begin{mybox}{Démontage de }
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture8.JPG}%
\hspace{10px}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Picture9.JPG}
\tcblower
\underline{Temps:}\\\\ 1 min.
\end{mybox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

I get this:
[image]

I am pretty happy with it, but there are things I want to fix. First is the numbering. I want them to be 1,2,3,... not 0.1,0.2,etc (I know they're doing this because I have created any titles).

Then I want to add arrows. I actually don't care much about the vertical ones, I don't think they bring much, but the horizontal ones are important to show the attachment corresponds to that phase.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Why? Your co-worker has produced the chart. Why do you want to redo it? If you really do want to, what have you got so far by way of code? I wouldn't use **forest** for this. TikZ maybe, though it isn't entirely clear what the point is. **tcolorbox** maybe? **graphicx** for the graphics inclusion. Please provide a minimal example showing what you've got `\documentclass... \end{document}`.

Comment: Working on it, I will upload it once I have a somewhat ok version. Cheers